# Codeigniter: ArgumentErrorCount

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying create an edit profile function for a user. When the user submits the form, it updates the data in the database. But when I try to access the edit profile page I get this error:

Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Profile::editProfile(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Capstone/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

I'm passing $id in the function, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Model:

```
public function updateUser($id)
 {
    $data = array(
            'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
            'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
            'favouritebeer' => $this->input->post('favouritebeer'),
            'website' => $this->input->post('website'),
            'bio' => $this->input->post('bio')
            );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
    return $id;
 }

 public function getUser($id)
 {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query-row();        
 }
```

Controller:

```
public function editProfile($id)
    {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/editprofile');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    if(isset($_POST['updatechanges'])) {
            if($this->user_model->getUser($id)) {               
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Profile updated!');
                redirect('profile', 'refresh');
            }
        }

    }
```

View:

```
<div class ="container">

 <?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","Mydb");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, username, age, location, favouritebeer, website, bio FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
 ?>

<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>'s Profile</h2>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Auth/logout" style="color:darkblue">Logout</a>
</br>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Auth/logout" style="color:darkblue">Change password</a>
</br>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Auth/logout" style="color:darkblue">Change security question</a>

</br>
</br>
<body>
<form method ="POST">
<h4>Age:</h4> 
<input type="age" class="form-control" name="age" id="ageinput" value="<?php echo $row['age']; ?>">

<h4>Location:</h4>
<input type="location" class="form-control" name="location" id="locationinput" value="<?php echo $row['location']; ?>">
<h4>Favourite beer:</h4>
<input type="beer" class="form-control" name="favouritebeer" id="beerinput" value="<?php echo $row['favouritebeer']; ?>">
<h4>Website:</h4>
<input type="website" class="form-control" name="website" id="websiteinput" value="<?php echo $row['website']; ?>">

 <h3>Bio: </h3>
 <input type="bio" class="form-control" name="bio" id="bioinput" value="<?php echo $row['bio']; ?>">
```

Save Changes

```
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean form does not get populate on edit page but it somehow submitted

Comment: I can't access the page at all. When I remove $id from editProfile($id) in my controller, I can access it. The form is populated with data, but when I click submit it gives me Undefined variable: id.

Comment: Also codeigniter has own database library https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html  you can auto-load it. also use model to fetch items https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: can you share the code to call editProfile() function

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling this editProfile() function from view try the following code :
in view :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()/controller/editProfile/<?php echo $id;?>">edit </a>
```

and in controller :

```
function editProfile() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    // do more
}
```

and if you are calling this function from another function in the same controller try this :

```
$this->editProfile(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code. The below mentioned function have one errors in return place.
 public function getUser($id)
 {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();        
 }
```